# Angular http to Wiremock stub does Option instead of Delete with 200 -> Page continues to onRejected

Tags: java, angularjs, cors, wiremock

I have an AngularJS application with WireMock stubs. There is a button that calls a method to /api/deleteThis, using the following code:

```
onDeleteButtonClick() {
    this._deleteThis()
      .then(() => {
          this._setState(States.SUCCESS);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this._setState(States.FAIL);
      });
  }
```

and

```
  private _deleteThis() {
    return this.$http.delete('http://localhost:8080/api/deleteThis');
  }
```

My WireMock file:

```
{
  "request" : {
    "urlPattern" : "/api/deleteThis",
    "method" : "DELETE"
  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 200,
    "body" : "{}",
    "headers" : {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"
    }
  }
}
```

And

```
{
  "request" : {
    "urlPattern" : "/api/deleteThis",
    "method" : "OPTIONS"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "headers": {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, PATCH",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"
    }
  }
}
```

What I expect: When the function activates, it should call the Mock and receive a 200. Therefore the States should go to SUCCES. But instead, the states gets set to FAIL. The browser (firefox) network tab shows that a 200 call has been made, but it's an OPTION instead of a DELETE.

I have read alot of similar questions which all relate to the CORS. I understand why the OPTION call is made, but I do not understand why the method chooses to go into onRejected while it receives a 200 (even though it's another type).

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

To get more information, log the error response:

```
onDeleteButtonClick() {
    this._deleteThis()
      .then(() => {
          this._setState(States.SUCCESS);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this._setState(States.FAIL);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you solved the issue, but I answer for other people.

When you send a request from angular and it is different of "GET", angular sends two requests (CORS policy):

- First, it sends an Options, to check if "Delete" operation (or whatever) is allowed.
- If this request receives a 200 with the appropiate headers, Angular sends your Delete request.

So, you need to create two stubs in wiremock:

```
{
  "request" : {
    "urlPattern" : "/api/deleteThis",
    "method" : "OPTIONS"
  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 200,
    "body" : "{}",
    "headers" : {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Toke"
    }
  }
}

{
  "request" : {
    "urlPattern" : "/api/deleteThis",
    "method" : "DELETE"
  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 200,
    "body" : "{}",
    "headers" : {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"
    }
  }
}
```

Regards.